# Passing schema name from a variable to create dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to write a function to create dataframe where the schema name is passed as argument to the function.

```
def extract_file(self, file_location={}):
    for (key, value) in file_location.items():
        print(key, " :: ", value)
        schema_name = 'schema_' + key
        # read the file and create a data frame
        df = self.spark.read \
            .format('csv') \
            .options(header='true', delimiter='|') \
            .schema(schema_name) \
            .load(exec('"{}"'.format(value)))
```

The above code is not working since it expects the argument of schema without quotes. How do I pass the argument from a variable storing string without quotes?

Comment: I did try following code but it doesn't work: .schema(schema_name.replace("'", ""))

Comment: Can you please add an example of the `file_location` dictionary? schema can be a [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType) or an [ddl-formated string](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/20392/what-is-meant-by-specifying-a-ddl-formatted-schema.html).